# Apache DirectorySlash seems not to be working

Tags: apache, apache2, directory, slash

I am facing problems with a site that I am trying to deploy. The site is working fine on my development host, but fails on deployment. Both hosts have a very similar configuration, both are Ubuntu Linux distros (dev: 11.10, deploy: 10.04), both use apache2, etc.

Both sites have mod_dir enabled, but the deployment one seems not to add the trailing slash to directory names, while the development one does. So, when I enter this URL (removed http to avoid silly stackoverflow antispam filtering):

> devel.mydomain.com/admin

The development host redirects it to:

> devel.mydomain.com/admin/

In deployment `http://mydomain.com/admin` is not redirected to mydomain.com/admin/ for unknown reasons, and I end with a 404 error. Of course if I enter `mydomain.com/admin/`, adding the trailing slash by hand, it works as expected. But I rather like to redirect also `mydomain.com/admin` to `mydomain.com/admin/`

The question is WHY in devel mod_dir seems to be doing the redirection and in deployment it does not.

I have done a grep within configuration files to see if the DirectorySlash directive was being disabled somewhere and found nothing. It is neither enabled explicitly on devel, so I think it should be on by default. Anyway I add this to my .htaccess file on deployment host:

DirectorySlash on

But it did not work neither.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

The `/admin` folder is password protected. I did not think that this was relevant, but in fact it is.

Also I have these rules on my `.htaccess` file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

The problem is related to [this](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3688208.htm) - see [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/htaccess-and-subdirectories#post-454369) for a good explanation.

Basically, when Apache generates a 401 error to ask the browser for a password, it also generates another request that does not use any folder, directory, or symlink, so it is redirected to `index.php`.

The workaround is to add this to the `.htaccess` file on site root folder:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /error/null.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error/null.html
```

and create that file, for example like this:

```
touch ./error/null.html
```

These are not *best practices* but they'll do for now while I look for a better solution.